# How to make a button stay at a fixed position in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer

In my webpage I have following code, basically, a button, two radio buttons and a label,

```
<tr>
        <td class="primary-BL1" style="text-align:right; width:18%">
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="SubmitButton_Click" CssClass="button" />
        </td>
        <td class="primary-BL1" style="text-align:left; width:34%">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblVerification" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="V">Verified</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NV">Not Verified</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        <td class="primary-BL1" style="text-align:left; width:48%">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CallReasonMessageLabel" CssClass="required"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When I click the submit button, if the label shows some error message, the position of the button will move to the left a little bit. How should I do to make the button stay in the fixed position? This only happens in IE8, not IE7.

Answer (score 1):

try to set a fixed width to the first cell, for example 200px:

```
<td class="primary-BL1" style="text-align:right; width:200px">
    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="SubmitButton_Click" CssClass="button" />
</td>
```

if you use percentages for the cells, in some browsers it will be fixed according to it contents

in other way, i recommend you to use divs instead of tables. if you are not good with css, you can use css frameworks to place your items in a cleaner way. i hardly recommend [bootstrap's grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)